# *Update* Sharrre: Getting a 400 (Bad Request) from Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using [Sharrre](http://sharrre.com/) for creating custom share buttons with counters.

I succesfully implemented a Facebook and Google+ button with it - but the Twitter button won't show up.

The console shows the following:

```
 GET https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%2Fthe-ultimate-packing-list%2F&callback=jQuery1102017237635073252022_1390276918007&_=1390276918008 400 (Bad Request)
```

I expected the `url=` to include the http and the domain - currently it only has the last part after the TLD.

Anyways, if I click on the message, it shows

`jQuery110209057587422430515_1390379775621({"request":"\/1\/urls\/count.json?url=%2Fthe-ultimate-packing-list%2F&callback=jQuery110209057587422430515_1390379775621&_=1390379775622","error":"Missing or invalid url parameter."});`

Any hints on how to make it work with the Sharrre plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it but it remains mysterious how. In the post-meta.php where I place the buttons it originally was like this

```
<div id="twitter" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-title="Share on Twitter"></div>
```

Playing around and analyzing the error message, I tried the following and it works:

```
<div id="twitter" data-url="http://thedomain.com<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-title="Share on Twitter"></div>
```

AFAIK the_permalink includes that first part of the domain already, but somehow it gets lost in the process.